# Having trouble keeping my variable constant

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to set my sum variable to stay the same after it has been initialized, but when I reuse num1 and num2 it resets sum despite the "final int sum". Also I don't want to go through the trouble of making two more dice methods(and don't know how) so making the sum constant is all I need.

```
  package crapsapp;
  public class CrapsApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int roll = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag){
        roll++;
        num1 = getDice(1,6);
        num2 = getDice(1,6);
        final int sum = (num1 + num2);
        if(roll == 1 ){
        switch(sum){
            case 2: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1 + num2)+ ", you lost..");flag=false;break;
            case 3: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1 + num2)+ ", you lost..");flag=false;break;
            case 12: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1 + num2)+ ", you lost..");
            flag=false;
            break;  

            case 7: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1 + num2)+ ", you won!"); flag=false;break;
            case 11: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1 + num2)+ ", you won!");
            flag=false;
            break;

            case 4: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");break;
            case 5: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");break;
            case 6: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");break;
            case 8: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");break;
            case 9: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");break;
            case 10: System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(sum)+ "... you roll again.");
            roll++;
            break;                
        }//end of switch  
            }//end of if

        else if(roll==3) {
            while(num1+num2!=sum||num1+num2!=7){
                num1 = getDice(1,6);
                num2 = getDice(1,6);
                System.out.println(num1+" "+num2+" "+sum+" ");
                if(num1+num2!=sum&&num1+num2!=7){
                System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1+num2)+ "... you roll again.");
                } 
               else if(num1+num2==7){
                System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1+num2)+ ", you lost..");
                 System.exit(0);
             }//end of if 
             //end of else if
            else if(num1+num2==sum) {
                System.out.println("You rolled " +num1+ " and " +num2+ ". The sum of your two numbers is " +(num1+num2)+ ", you won!");
                System.exit(0);
            }//end of else if
             }//end of while 
        }//end of else if
        }//end of while
    }//end of main

 public static int getDice(){
   int num1;
   num1 = (1+ (int)(Math.random() *6));
   return num1;
}

 public static int getDice(int min, int max){
   int num2;
   num2 = (1+ (int)(Math.random() *6));
   return num2;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `int sum = -1;` to before the `while(flag)`

then in the loop do

```
if (sum != -1)  {
   sum = (num1 + num2);
}
```

seems a bit strange that you want to do this though

Comment: Should I be making a new if statement or use the one up top? Also if not then which while loop does it go in? Doesn't seem to work as sum stays as -1, when I make a new if statement right under the first while loop.